# How to use mapStateToProps in class component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

**Login.js in functional component**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../actions/auth';


const Login = ({ login, isAuthenticated }) => {
    return (
        <div>
           // some code here
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(Login);
```

How can I use above mapStateToProps function in class component as I used above in functional component?

**Login.js in class component**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class Login extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            search:'',
        }
    }
    render() {
        return(
        <div> 
             //some code here
        </div>
        )
     }
}
export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

In class components `mapStateToProps` works the same as functional components, I feel there are only differences in some syntax or calling approaches.

> It does not matter if a mapStateToProps function is written using the function keyword (function mapState(state) { } ) or as an arrow function
> (const mapState = (state) => { } ) - it will work the same either way.

**Class component with `mapStateToProps`**

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login } from '../actions/auth';

class Login extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            search:'',
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated } = this.props;
        return(
        <div> 
             //some code here
        </div>
        )
     }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { isAuthenticated } = state.auth.isAuthenticated
  return { isAuthenticated }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login)
```

As you can see there is only 1 major difference is: In **Class component** we are reading the value `isAuthenticated` from `this.props` whereas in the **Functional component** we are getting the value as arguments.

For information read more about `mapStateToProps`. https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate